# What happens to people that gamble in Arizona when they're not old enough?

Tags: minor, gambling, arizona

I was gambling in Arizona 2013 and was looking for a goal of $1,000. It wasn't a scam. I was 10 years old at the time. We got only got $300.  Both and my Dad were doing the gambling and we each took turns.

What would happen if someone reported us?

Comment: What do you mean by "gambling?"  Playing games of chance in a casino?  And what do you mean "reported?"  Called police?  Have you done a search for "Arizona gambling laws?"

Answer (score 5):

[This site](https://www.onlineunitedstatescasinos.com/states/arizona-gambling/) says that the legal age for online gambling in AZ is 18, and for "land" gambling is 21, but does not mention penalties for violations.

According to Arizona code section [13-3301](https://www.azleg.gov/viewdocument/?docName=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.azleg.gov%2Fars%2F13%2F03301.htm) "Regulated gambling" requires that

> Beginning on June 1, 2003, none of the players is under twenty-one years of age.

According to [13-3302](https://www.azleg.gov/viewdocument/?docName=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.azleg.gov%2Fars%2F13%2F03302.htm) Regulated gambling is "not unlawful" provided that

> the gambling is conducted in accordance with the statutes, rules or orders governing the gambling.

Acording to [13-3303](https://www.azleg.gov/viewdocument/?docName=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.azleg.gov%2Fars%2F13%2F03303.htm):

> A. Except for amusement, regulated or social gambling, a person commits promotion of gambling if he knowingly does either of the following for a benefit:
>
> 1. Conducts, organizes, manages, directs, supervises or finances gambling.
> 2. Furnishes advice or assistance for the conduct, organization, management, direction, supervision or financing of gambling.
>
> B. Promotion of gambling is a class 5 felony.

So it would appear that the organizer could be guilty of a felony if underage gambling is allowed in a regulated gambling situation, which seems to be what the question is describing. I cannot find any AZ law imposing penalties on an underage person who engages in gambling, but  I am not sure if there are any or not.

I suspect in the situation described in the question, it would be treated as if the father was doing the gambling, but the description is not entirely clear.

Comment: Or the owner or operator of the establishment would kick them out, mostly so the operator is not in violation of the law.

Comment: @Damila  The law seems designed to induce the owner to do just that.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I was just giving an alternative to your last line of what our likely happen. Bottom line is it does not appear to be a crime for the minor who is there, but letting him participate is either a crime or a violation of the license.